# Theories how they arrived at this Ebola growth forecast? Not regression

Tags: regression, forecasting

The 21,000 estimate for Oct. was certainly not via quad or power regression.
I wonder how they got that number?

[image]
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/ebola/11121045/Graphic-how-Ebola-cases-have-grown-since-March.html

Comment: I remember seeing simple deterministic, differential equation models for diseases -- something like http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/loci/joma/the-sir-model-for-spread-of-disease-the-differential-equation-model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original source seems to be the CDC report [Estimating the Future Number of Cases in the Ebola Epidemic — Liberia and Sierra Leone, 2014–2015](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/su6303a1.htm?s_cid=su6303a1_w).

This cites [Chowell G, et al 2004](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022519304001092) for the original methodology, and briefly describes it as as a Markov chain model with parameters sourced from prior outbreaks.

Their (Excel) implementation of the model is also [linked](http://dx.doi.org/10.15620/cdc.24900).